# Aligning elements vertically not horizontally using css grid

Tags: html, css

Can I align this grid vertically not horizontally to have 1,2,3… On the left site not on top ? I am using vue js

```
<div class="board">
      <div v-for="index in this.board.boardSize" :key="index">
        <div class="board-field" :id="index">{{ index }}</div>
      </div>
</div>
```

[image]

```
.container {
  margin: 10px 140px 10px 140px;
}
.board {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(15, 1fr);
  grid-template-columns: repeat(20, 1fr);
}
.board-field {
  border: 2px solid var(--mainTextColor);
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

Comment: `grid-auto-flow:column`